# How did I manage to not be hurt after accidentally making an electric contact between mains wires?

Tags: mains, shock

**Warning: mains is dangerous, often fatal and should not be messed with.**

I accidentally touched *both live and neutral* of a 230 AC mains via dupont wires after a shower (still wet feet). However I merely felt a muscle-interrupting itch rather than any deadly consequence. **This shall need luck and I strongly discourage anyone to try this.**  However, what is the underlying cause that saved me from a deadly shock?

Comment: Seriously, STOP MESSING ABOUT!!!! You will get yourself killed. This is not clever, it is STUPID. Other people may read your question and try the same thing. This is really irresponsible.

Comment: Sorry for that. I was hot headed. Just to be curious about why I was still alive. Or what I have done actually to save myself from a deadly shock and arrhythmia.

Comment: You're still alive because you didn't have good electrical contact with the ground. Next time you may be less lucky and get electrocuted or maybe seriously impaired. Be careful.

Comment: Btw I think it's a valid question and it deserves restoration, slight edits and a good answer with all the necessary warnings. @RogerRowland IMO it's better to explain what happened here and why YMMV than just count on people not trying to do the same.

Comment: @sharptooth My comment was a gut reaction to a question that might lead the OP or others into dangerous territory. IMHO it's better to be safe rather than sorry. I didn't ask the OP to edit or delete, my comment was a red flag to *any* readers. By all means feel free to answer the original question if you prefer. I'll stick to trying to keep everyone alive and kicking.

Comment: So I restored the question with more warnings. Please forgive my previous mistakes.

Comment: @user2513881 That's a better question, thanks. I've revoked my downvote.

Comment: My fault. I don't take pleasure in kicking people into hospitals -- or funeral.

Comment: Enough with the nanny-speak already! Yes we know 230 V is dangerous. No, we don't want to hear about it every time someone mentions it. Also, what's a "dupont wire"?

Comment: See http://www.engineershop.net/qita/40pcs.jpg

Comment: @OlinLathrop Better to have a warning that let someone electrocute himself. Seriously, I personally witnessed a person with a PhD in physics trying to measure "current in the outlet" by plugging a multimeter set to "measure current" into that outlet. I'm sure you would never do that but I saw how someone actually did it.

Comment: @sharp: A single warning is OK, but adding nanny warnings to the question is really over the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***HUGE WARNING Toying with mains can cause electrocution, injuries, impairment, fires, damage to property. Protect yourself. Don't work on live mains unless you're qualified to do so and follow all the required safety practices***

Your mileage may vary greatly depending on a lot of factors which together determine whether you have low enough resistance in the circuit formed by phase wire, your body and either neutral or ground. Your body resistance may vary within some range and that sometimes can make a difference. In this specific case the most likely factor is that the DuPont wires you used were rather thin and also the contact surface between them and the mains was also rather small and that together gave you a rather high resistance circuit so the current was rather low and not enough to cause serious damage.

I have a neat story of what once happened in a lower resistance scenario. Long ago I accidentally touched with the same finger both phase and neutral terminals of an electric outlet with cover off and live wires connected. The voltage was 220 volts AC. 10 amperes automatic breaker tripped immediately and I've got a two millimeters deep and about five millimeters wide burn to carbon color on my finger. Automatic breakers take dozens of minutes to trip if current is only slightly higher than cut-off value (20% if I recall correctly - so it'd be 12 amperes for about an hour in this example) and tripping immediately only happens when current is much, much higher than the cut-off value. This time it only went through part of a single finger and burnt skin to carbon color. Should it go through body it would most certainly be fatal and you would not get this answer from me.

Comment: I was stunned by the amperage. Why your body has got so little resistance (around 22R). I have noted that normally people have kOhms or even MOhms across their body.

Comment: @user2513881 Those jigaohms happen across the entire body. In this case the distance between the terminals (and where they touched the body) was perhaps 20 millimeters.

Comment: It's worth adding that RCD's / GFCI's will (probably) save you if you complete a circuit between phase and earth. But in this situation, shorting between phase and neutral, a RCD __won't save you__. The lesson is: having RCD protection is no excuse to be stupid with electricity.